# Specifying the requirements for class template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have few classes that look like this:

```
struct neg_inf {
    constexpr double operator()() { return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); }
};

struct pos_inf {
    constexpr double operator()() { return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); }
};

template<typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound>
class limit {
    dX dx;
    UpperBound upperBound;
    LowerBound lowerBound;
    double step_size;

    limit( dX x, LowerBound lower, UpperBound upper, double step = 1 ) :
        dx{ x }, lowerBound{ lower }, upperBound{ upper }, step_size{ step }
    {}

    dX value() const { return dx; }
    LowerBound lower() const { return lowerBound; }
    UpperBound upper() const { return upperBound; }
    double step() const { return step_size; }            
};
```

These classes so far work as intended. Now I want to modify the template arguments using conditionals such as `std::enable_if_t`, `std::is_arithemtic` `std::is_same`.

These are the conditions that need to be met to instantiate a limit object.

> - `dX` must be at least `arithmetic` and `numerical`
> - `Lower` & `Upper` `bound` must be either `numerical`, `arithmetic` or `neg_inf` or `pos_inf`.

For example these are valid instantiations:

```
dX = 1st and can be any: int, long, float, double, /*complex*/, etc.

limit< 1st, 1st, 1st >     // default template

limit< 1st, 1st, pos_inf >  // these will be specializations
limit< 1st, 1st, neg_inf >
limit< 1st, pos_inf, 1st >
limit< 1st, neg_inf, 1st >
limit< 1st, pos_inf, pos_inf >
limit< 1st, neg_inf, neg_inf >
limit< 1st, neg_inf, pos_inf >
limit< 1st, pos_inf, neg_inf >
```

These are the valid conditions for instantiating my template. I am planning on partially specializing this class when either or both `UpperBound` and or `LowerBound` are an `infinity` type. When the `upper` and `lower` bounds are numerical - arithmetic types, the general or default template will handle them.

My question is what would the `template declaration` to my class look like with the `type_traits` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to restrict template type to class is to add extra parameter for SFINAE:

```
template <typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound, typename Enabler = void>
class limit;
```

and then, provide specialization with appropriate SFINAE

```
template <typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound>
class limit<dX,
            LowerBound,
            UpperBound,
            std::enable_if_t<my_condition<dX, LowerBound, UpperBound>::value>>
{
    // ...
};
```

So in your case, `my_condition` should be something like

```
template <typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound>
using my_condition =
    std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<dX>,
                     std::disjunction<std::is_arithmetic<LowerBound>,
                                      std::is_same<LowerBound, neg_inf>,
                                      std::is_same<LowerBound, pos_inf>>,
                      std::disjunction<std::is_arithmetic<UpperBound>,
                                       std::is_same<UpperBound, neg_inf>,
                                       std::is_same<UpperBound, pos_inf>>
                      >;
```

An other way, is `static_assert`:

```
template <typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound>
class limit
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<dX>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<LowerBound>::value
                  || std::is_same<LowerBound, neg_inf>::value
                  || std::is_same<LowerBound, pos_inf>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<UpperBound>::value
                  || std::is_same<UpperBound, neg_inf>::value
                  || std::is_same<UpperBound, pos_inf>::value, "!");
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I like your answer, but SFINAE is something that I'm still getting a grasp on. I understand what it means and I have even implemented it in some cases where it was easy to implement, but now this limit class is a small beast... and the syntax gets wordy and one wrong mistake and Visual Studio blows up with its compiler errors lol!

Comment: I'll have to try that!

Comment: You might prefer `static_assert`. But IMO the "hard"/verbose part is mostly the trait.

Comment: `static_assert` could work; but I think I like the SFINAE approach. It's a little harder to setup up but once it's up and working, should work like a charm!

Comment: When you provided me with an example: the line `template <typename dX, class LowerBound, class UpperBound` is there a typo here? Did you forget to include either a `,` or a `>` before the `using` declaration?

Comment: @FrancisCugler: typo fixed.

Comment: Hmm I tried your approach, but `my_condition` is not resolving when using it within `enable_if_t` within my class declaration. Visual Studio is giving me the hint: `using std::enable_if_t< < error-constant > > = < error type> name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`

Comment: I could append my changes to the bottom of this question, or I could start a new question with my attempted applied changes to your proposal.

Comment: Never mind I had a small over looked typo in my IDE, I had a `:` instead of a `::` between one of the `type_trait` templates. Once I fixed that everything resolved.

Comment: Nice, even though I wasn't intending to have this work with `char` types because it was meant for basic algebraic expressions, I tested it with chars for example:  `limit<char,char,char> l( 'a', 'a', 'Z' );` and left the step size as default and sure enough it does work since `char` is arithmetic type.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: Notice that `'a'`-`'z'` is not guarantied to be contiguous though (even more when mixing case). `'0'`-`'9'` is.

Comment: True, but like I said I was not intending the for the class to be used with chars.

Answer (score 2):

Witht the upcoming `C++20` standard, we will get [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) and [constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). With that in mind, we can declare our own concepts and get rid of SFINAE.

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

struct neg_inf {
    constexpr double operator()() { return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); }
};

struct pos_inf {
    constexpr double operator()() { return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); }
};

template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template<typename T>
concept Bound = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>     || 
                std::is_same_v<T, neg_inf>  ||
                std::is_same_v<T, pos_inf>;

template<Arithmetic dX, Bound LowerBound, Bound UpperBound>
class limit {
 private:   
    dX dx;
    UpperBound upperBound;
    LowerBound lowerBound;
    double step_size;

public:
    limit() = default;
    limit( dX x, LowerBound lower, UpperBound upper, double step = 1 ) :
        dx{ x }, lowerBound{ lower }, upperBound{ upper }, step_size{ step }
    {}

    dX value() const { return dx; }
    LowerBound lower() const { return lowerBound; }
    UpperBound upper() const { return upperBound; }
    double step() const { return step_size; }            
};
```

### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/wGVoz-)

Comment: I really like this answer, but at the moment I'm limited to c++17 and do not have access c++20 so I have to settle for SFINAE... I do appreciate your answer for a possible future design-implementation.